# Json_table function in oracle forms 12c

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I am fairly new to the oracle forms. I have a requirement of using the json_table function. When i run the below query I get the error message mentioned below. But when I run the same query in sql developer it works. Would be great if someone could help me find out the rootcause for the same. Thank you.

```
SELECT RPTD.GROUP_TODO_ID,
       query_json.event_id
  into :GLOBAL.RVS_ID,:GLOBAL.RV_EV_ID
  FROM RGTD ,
       RPTD
      ,json_table(RGTD.REVSHARE_INFO, '$' COLUMNS ( NESTED PATH '$.revenueShareFunds[*]' COLUMNS ( ID 
                  VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$.rapId' , EVENT_ID VARCHAR2(12) PATH '$.revenueShareEventId'))) 
                  query_json
  WHERE QUERY_JSON.ID = 'xxxxx'
    AND RGTD.ID             = RPTD.GROUP_TODO_ID
    AND rownum              =1;
```

## Error I get while compiling the 12c oracle forms :

```
Compiling PRE-QUERY trigger on REVSHARE_PART_TO_DO data block...
Compilation error on PRE-QUERY trigger on REVSHARE_PART_TO_DO data block:
PL/SQL ERROR 103 at line 23, column 95
Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
The symbol ")" was substituted for ";" to continue.
```

Answer (score 1):

For the recent versions of Forms(**10**,**11**), even the explicit join was not possible within the forms. So, you rather can put the query into a stored procedure within the DB such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Get_ID_Values( 
                                           i_json_id  IN  VARCHAR2, 
                                           o_rvs_id   OUT rptd.group_todo_id%type, 
                                           o_rv_ev_id OUT VARCHAR2, 
                                           o_error    OUT VARCHAR2 
                                          ) 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT rptd.group_todo_id, query_json.event_id
      INTO o_rvs_id, o_rv_ev_id
      FROM rgtd
      JOIN rptd
        ON rgtd.id = rptd.group_todo_id
     CROSS JOIN json_table(rgtd.revshare_info,
                      '$' COLUMNS(NESTED PATH '$.revenueShareFunds[*]'
                              COLUMNS(id VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$.rapId',
                                      event_id VARCHAR2(12) PATH
                                      '$.revenueShareEventId'))) query_json
     WHERE query_json.id = i_json_id
       AND rownum = 1;
  EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN o_error := 'No Data Found';
            WHEN   others      THEN o_error := sqlerrm;      
END;
/
```

all call that from the current `PRE-QUERY` trigger.

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Getting the same error and i am using oracle 12c

Comment: @VimalBhaskar Can you edit the question with the code How you call the stored procedure from the trigger ?